# SQLite3 data with dual primary keys displaying incorrectly

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database composed of three tables. Table #1 ("meta_events") has one primary key; Table #2 ("meta_datasets") has one primary key; and Table #3 ("meta_points") has two primary keys, both of which are foreign keys to tables 1 and 2, respectively.

When I view the data in Table #3, I see that one of the primary keys ("EQ_ID") has n.1, n.2, etc. Because it is a dual/composite primary key, this is a unique pair. I don't understand why the n.1, n.2, etc. has been added.

Below is the code I ran in SQLite to get the table schemas and Table #3 ("meta_points") data. The returned TXT and CSV are also below. Thanks for any help.

**SQLite code**:

```
sqlite3 Copyofdatabase1.db
.output myschemas.txt
.schema meta_events
.schema meta_datasets
.schema meta_points
.mode columns
.header on
.output table_meta_points.csv
select * from meta_points;
.quit
```

**myschemas.txt output:**

```
CREATE TABLE META_EVENTS (EQ_ID integer, Style integer, EQ_Name text, Date_Updated datetime, Region text, EPSG_Degrees integer, EPSG_UTM integer, Hypo_Depth_km float, Style_Source text, Hypo_Latitude float, Mw float, Source_File text, flag_volcanic boolean, Date date, Hypo_Source text, Hypo_Longitude float, flag_glaciated boolean, PRIMARY KEY (EQ_ID));
CREATE TABLE META_DATASETS (DS_ID integer, flag_pt boolean, Date_Updated datetime, Citation text, Source_File text, flag_rup boolean, is_used boolean, flag_geo boolean, PRIMARY KEY (DS_ID));
CREATE TABLE META_POINTS (Completion text, Location_Basis text, Date_Updated datetime, FZW_Unc_Type text, EQ_ID integer, Vertical_Direction_Pos text, Supplementary_PT_DS_ID text, Meas_Type text, Lateral_Direction_Pos text, DS_ID integer, EPSG_Original integer, Source_File text, Displ_Unc_Type text, PRIMARY KEY (EQ_ID, DS_ID), FOREIGN KEY (EQ_ID) REFERENCES META_EVENTS (EQ_ID), FOREIGN KEY (DS_ID) REFERENCES META_DATASETS (DS_ID));
```

**table_meta_points.csv output**

```
Completion  Location_Basis       Date_Updated         FZW_Unc_Type  EQ_ID       Vertical_Direction_Pos  Supplementary_PT_DS_ID  Meas_Type                       Lateral_Direction_Pos  DS_ID       EPSG_Original  Source_File                       Displ_Unc_Type
----------  -------------------  -------------------  ------------  ----------  ----------------------  ----------------------  ------------------------------  ---------------------  ----------  -------------  --------------------------------  --------------
Complete    GPS from Originator  2019-02-25 18:52:48  1-sigma       1           n/a                                             Subpixel correlation and field  RL                     3           32611          Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  1-sigma       
Complete    Digitized by Origin  2019-02-25 18:52:48  No Info       1.1         Not Specified                                   field                           RL                     6           26911          Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Field Geology 
Complete    Digitized by Origin  2019-02-25 18:52:48  No Info       2           Varies                                          field                           Not Distinguished      2           4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Field Geology 
Complete    GPS from Originator  2019-02-25 18:52:48  1-sigma       2.1         n/a                                             Subpixel correlation and field  RL                     3           32611          Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  1-sigma       
Complete    Digitized by Origin  2019-02-25 18:52:48  No Info       2.2         Not Specified                                   field                           RL                     6           4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Field Geology 
Incomplete  GPS from Originator  2019-02-25 18:52:48  No Info       3           Varies                                          field                           Varies                 18          4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Field Geology 
Likely nea  GPS from Originator  2019-02-25 18:52:48  Not Applicab  4           n/a                                             Subpixel correlation and air-p  LL                     23          4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  95% Confidence
Onshore co  Digitized by Origin  2019-02-25 18:52:48  Not Applicab  5           Varies                                          field                           Not Distinguished      6           4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Not Applicable
Complete    Digitized by Origin  2019-02-25 18:52:48  Not Applicab  6           Not Specified                                   field                           RL                     6           4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Not Applicable
Complete    Digitized by Origin  2019-02-25 18:52:48  Not Applicab  7           Not Specified                                   field                           RL                     6           4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Not Applicable
Complete    Digitized by Origin  2019-02-25 18:52:48  Not Applicab  8           Not Distinguished                               field                           Not Distinguished      6           4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Not Applicable
Onshore co  Digitized by Origin  2019-02-25 18:52:48  Not Applicab  9           Not Distinguished                               field                           Not Distinguished      6           4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Not Applicable
Complete    GPS from Originator  2019-02-25 18:52:48  Not Applicab  10          Not Distinguished       40;                     field                           Not Distinguished      39          4326           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Field Geology 
Complete    GPS from Originator  2019-02-25 18:52:48  Not Applicab  10.1        Not Distinguished       39;                     field                           Not Distinguished      40          4267           Static_Master_List_rev7 | POINTS  Field Geology
```

Comment: Are you saying there is no row in Table#1 (meta_events) with 1.1 EQ_ID? Or are you saying the row has EQ_ID = 1, but the csv is showing 1.1? I think the question is unclear to me.

Comment: If you want CSV output, you need to use `.mode csv`. Though `.dump` works better for getting sample data that we can copy and paste to recreate the tables. What you have now is really hard to import.